# UNITY 3D - "Physics.Raycast" not working when starting position is changed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, position

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;

public class Gun : MonoBehaviour {

    [Header("References")]
    [SerializeField] private GunData gunData;
    [SerializeField] private Transform muzzle;

    float timeSinceLastShot;

    private void Start()
    {
        PlayerShoot.shootInput += Shoot;
    }

    private bool CanShoot() => !gunData.reloading && timeSinceLastShot > 1f / (gunData.fireRate / 60f);

    public void Shoot()
    {
        if (gunData.currentAmmo > 0)
    {
        if (CanShoot())
        {
            if (Physics.Raycast(muzzle.position, transform.forward, out RaycastHit hitInfo, gunData.maxDistance))
            {
                Debug.Log(hitInfo.transform.name);
            }
            gunData.currentAmmo--;
            timeSinceLastShot = 0;
            OnGunShot();
        }
    }
    }
    private void Update() {
        timeSinceLastShot += Time.deltaTime;

        Debug.DrawRay(muzzle.position, muzzle.forward);
    }

    private void OnGunShot() {
        
    }

}
```

I changed the starting position of the raycast from the gun transform position to the gun's muzzle position. Before I did that the raycast worked fine from the "transform.postion". in the inspector I put the muzzle in the field.
I tried using a "Debug.DrawRay" to see if the ray was still there, and nothing showed up. I was using a tutorial on youtube but the guy seemed to have no problems.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kXbQMhwj5Uc < Tutorial I was using.

if more information is required, I can give out more in the comments

Answer (score 0):

the guy in the tutorial is using :

```
private void Update() {
        timeSinceLastShot += Time.deltaTime;

        Debug.DrawRay(cam.position, cam.forward * gunData.maxDistance);
    }
```

and if you want to keep your code you need to add speed to your ray :

```
[SerializeField] private int shootSpeed;
private void Update() {
    timeSinceLastShot += Time.deltaTime;

    Debug.DrawRay(muzzle.position, muzzle.forward * shootSpeed);
}
```

or like the guy but with muzzle :

```
private void Update() {
    timeSinceLastShot += Time.deltaTime;

    Debug.DrawRay(muzzle.position, muzzle.forward * gunData.maxDistance);
}
```

Comment: I tried using the fixes. its still not showing a debug ray. and nothing is logging to the console. at this point im thinking its a problem with my version of unity. "2021.3.1.10f1"

Comment: hi @Darkryker19  did you look in your scriptable object if the ammunition was not as 0?

Comment: And did you see the ray cast in the scene when you are playing if not are all the gizmos enabled ?

Comment: I Checked; ammunition is not zero. and when checking in the scene I did not see the ray cast.